# Reading manifest.mf inside .war file from url using java

Tags: java

I am trying to read the MANIFEST.MF file from inside the file.war.. It is inside the folder META-INF.
I have this code, but I am getting null pointer exception. Advise please? Thank you!

```
String warurl = "http://.../file.war";

try{
URL url = new URL(warurl);
InputStream inputStream = url.openStream().getClass().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

}catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println("Error reading manifest file.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve a resource from the classloader of the InputStream of the URL: `openStream().getClass()` - that's not the same as getting it from the war file that the URL points to.

You should use a `JarURLConnection`. An example from the Javadoc of this standard API class:

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file:/home/duke/duke.jar!/");
JarURLConnection jarConnection = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();
Manifest manifest = jarConnection.getManifest();
```

This also gives you a handy `Manifest` object to retrieve data from the manifest.

Comment: Hi Erwin, can i also use JarURLConnection for my .war file as well? thanks!

Comment: @ashlrem Yes a war file is a jar file. Just a different extension, but same thing. Actually they are both zip files so you can also use classes that read from zip files.

Comment: alright cool. i did try to use the `URL(jar:file:/.../../file.jar);` however, i am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: It should be `jar:http://.../file.war!/` (so it starts with `jar:` and ends with `!/`, but in the middle should be your original URL with the extension ending in `.war` in your case - and of course a local `file://` is better and more reliable than a remote `http://`)

Comment: fantastic! Thank you very much. You're a legend!